# skip after_update if given field is the only updated attribute - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a model that can be updated twice within the same update request.

Here is my filter:

```
after_update :make_api_call
```

In my function, I update the api and then save the response on the same object.

```
def make_api_call
    response = SomeAPI.call    
    self.api_response = response
    self.save
end
```

This will obviously cause the update function to be called in an endless loop. I want the `make_api_call` function to be skipped if the only attribute being updated is the `api_response` attribute. Executing the API call before update is not an option do to some nested resources associated with the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ActiveRecord::Persistence#update_columns](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns) which skips callbacks.

```
def make_api_call
  response = SomeAPI.call    
  update_columns(api_response: response)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 5.1 you could also do:

```
after_update :make_api_call, unless: :saved_change_to_response?
```

The `saved_change_to_response?` method comes from `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty`, which allows us to check if a specific attribute has changed by prepending `saved_change_to_` to the attribute name.